# Xamarin IOS deployment fails. FileNotFoundException on info.plist

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin app which will not run. It builds fine but then fails with a FileNotFoundException:

> Error: error MT1006: Could not install the application
>   '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Myapp.Mobile.iOS/08e15c960b43270f23a396facbda4524/bin/iPhone/Debug/myapp.Mobile.iOS.app'
>   on the device 'Counter's iPad': Could not find required file
>   '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Myapp.Mobile.iOS/08e15c960b43270f23a396facbda4524/bin/iPhone/Debug/myapp.Mobile.iOS.app/Info.plist'..
>   . Please check the logs for more details.

I'm not sure what is up here - the info.plist file exists in the root of my iOS app and the app builds OK.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the normal issue with visual studio.

Delete `bin` and `obj` folder under the application, and run again.

Comment: I am still getting this issue now with VS2019.  I deleted the bin and obj on the PC, no difference, but if I delete the Mac folder it refers to, it works again for a while.